# Getting GCC error: "sys/memfd.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, include, system-calls

I'm trying to use the `memfd_create` syscall in my C code. I tried to include `sys/memfd.h` as the man page for `memfd_create` says is appropriate, but GCC gives me an error "sys/memfd: No such file or directory".

I've tried Googling around and couldn't find anyone having the same problem. I noticed some versions of the manpage for `memfd_create` say that I should include `sys/mman.h`, but it didn't seem to help when I tried it. It would say `memfd_create` was implicitly declared.

Here is a minimal reproduction of my problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#include <sys/mman.h>

#include <sys/memfd.h>



int main(){

        int fd;
        fd = memfd_create("test", MFD_CLOEXEC);

        return 0;
}
```

I expect the above code to compile and run without error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ubuntu man-pages in Bionic (18.04) are not up to date with this API (including its implementation in Bionic).

[The Focal man-page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man2/memfd_create.2.html) correctly shows how to include `memfd_create()`. It says:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE         /* See feature_test_macros(7) */
#include <sys/mman.h>
```

So you only need to include `<sys/mman.h>`, and you need to build with `-D_GNU_SOURCE` in your compiler flags. Or, do as the man page says and literally `#define _GNU_SOURCE` before including the header. However, I recommend just compiling with `-D_GNU_SOURCE` instead.

Comment: that does **not** work on "older" systems, like debian stable (9.9).

Comment: or centos 7. And yes, the manpage wrongly tells you to include `sys/memfd.h` on such systems, so teaching one how to type `man memfd_create` really is a bit rich.

Comment: @mosvy What's "rich" is telling people who're trying to help that what they do "is a bit rich." The question is tagged "ubuntu", and this is a possible answer. If it solves the OP's question, great. If not, then it won't.

Comment: [ubuntu manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/man2/memfd_create.2.html) (19.04). notice the `<sys/memfd.h>` and have a little sense of humor.

Comment: @NikosC. This worked! Thanks so much for your help! Coincidentally, I seem to remember coming across your answers before (maybe several times) so I really appreciate your contributions. May I ask why you prefer compiling with -D_GNU_SOURCE over putting the define in the code?

Comment: @chillsauce Because it avoids the problem of some other header including it first without defining the macro on some systems with a different glibc version. This can result in build failures. Defining it with a compiler flag avoids the issue. You'll find that most projects that depend on GNU and/or Linux, POSIX, SystemV or BSD specific library functions usually build with `-D_GNU_SOURCE -D_SVID_SOURCE -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE`.

Answer (score 6):

On older systems, you'll have to include `linux/memfd.h` for the `MFD_` defines, and call `memfd_create()` via the the `syscall(2)` wrapper (and include `unistd.h` and `sys/syscall.h` for it work).

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <linux/memfd.h>
#include <err.h>
int main(void){
        int fd;
        if((fd = syscall(SYS_memfd_create, "test", MFD_CLOEXEC)) == -1)
                err(1, "memfd_create");
        return 0;
}
```